# Insertion sort algorithm with sorted list

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am preparing for algorithm exam and have the following question: If we provide a sorted list to the `insertion sort algorithm`, would it still take O(n^2) ?

Answer (score 0):

No it should run in O(n) time as this is the best case for this algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort